# The sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working with SharePoint 2010 server. I have deployed a sandboxed solution to the sharepoint server. But while adding the webpart to page it shows the error like below.

**"The sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request"**

I found below article and followed all the work around, but the error is still persisting.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/08/error-the-sandboxed-code-execution-request-was-refused-because-the-sandboxed-code-host-service-was-too-busy-to-handle-the-request.aspx

Can anyone tell me what am I missing or what I have to do in order to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 6):

We've had to do this, too:

```
$uc = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUserCodeService]::Local
$uc.WorkerProcessExecutionTimeout = 5000
$uc.Update()

$tier = $uc.Tiers[""]   # default Tier has no Name
$tier.MaximumWorkerProcesses = 2    # number of CPU Cores + 1
$tier.Update()
```

Comment: For me it was enough to set _MaximumWorkerProcess_ property to 2.